# Broken NTFS Permissions for MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I have been "securing" our database server. To do this I removed some permissions from the folders that the SQL Express install created.

```
D:\SQL
D:\SQL\Data
D:\SQL\Backup
etc..
```

I kept the permissions on the Data folder as they were, but I removed anything I thought I didn't need from the others.

Now I can't backup databases. If I try selecting the backup location the dialog doesn't show anything in the d:\SQL folder and if I put the path in myself it tells me this:-

> Cannot access the specified path or file on the server. Verify that you have the necessary security privilages and that the path and file exists.
>
> ...

It looks like folder permission problem. Another server configured in a similar way has a bunch of "allow" permissions for an account called "`MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS`", (which I know I deleted), But I can't re-add these permissions because there is no such *group*, *user* or *built-in security principle* on the server.

How do I add permissions for this `MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS` account?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This account is a service SID.

The full name is `NT SERVICE\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: It seems that the Microsoft Training Kit book (for Exam 70-462) titled "Administering Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Databases" covers these Virtual Accounts or Managed Local Accounts, in chapter 1.

Answer (score 4):

If your server is in a domain, you must select the computer name location or
NT SERVICE\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS will not be found when adding the user to security rights