# .bak file not visible in any directory in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, backup, ssms

I have a .bak file created today by someone else, manually created through SSMS 2008 R2. I'm trying to manually restore the database, unfortunately the file isn't appearing when I go to browse it.

I can script the restore process, but I've seen this problem before and I'm not sure what could cause the .bak to not appear.

Comment: I'm going to write a script for the restore, I just want to know what is causing it. It's definitely a .bak, not a .bak.txt or anything.

Comment: So are you able to browse the folder where you *know* the file is, and it's not appearing? Or are you unable to browse to the folder?

Comment: I can browse to the folder, just not see any of the .bak files. I've checked the permissions of the user I'm running SSMS with, they're a local admin and the file isn't marked as "hidden" or anything.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot somewhere, showing Windows Explorer's view of the folder, and that of SSMS? Also explain in the question the process you are using to get to this step.

Comment: (Also note the SQL Server service account has to have permissions too, not just the SSMS user. Though that shouldn't prevent .bak files from showing in the list before you do anything with them.)

Comment: It's a shared environment and I'm not able to log on it at this point. I'll script the restore and post further details in the question if I'm able to reproduce the problem later.

Comment: In my case, SSMS connects to **another** server and the backup location is on that server (SSMS is able to browse that server, but not local computer). Therefore, the backup is not visible on local computer.

Comment: In my (and probably a typical case): This may be due to that one does not follow to restore from the [device] option first.   Even you store the .bak in the right path, it is initially NOT detectable from the [Source]->[Database] check box, until you follow the steps to restore via the [device] option https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/adventureworks-install-configure?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ssms The SQLserver need to do internal access right grants to users... etc..(even all the needed Windows properties are in place)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

We had the same issue today. It turned out to be a permissions issue, as illustrated in some of the other answers. The difference is that the account we needed to add was `NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER`.

[image: Screenshot]

I identified the account by comparing the permissions of the default SQL Backup folder permissions to the folder containing the backup file.

Adding the service account is not as simple as it sounds. Here is what worked for me (Server 2012 R2). The official MS docs are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-file-system-permissions-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-ver15).

1. Log into the server. (The change must be made on the actual server, not through a network share.)
2. Change the *Locations* to the local server name.
3. Type in `NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER` in the name box. (Do not click Check Names). If your SQL SERVER has a set instance name (i.e., you are connecting to MyComputer\[SQLSERVERINSTANCE]), enter `NT SERVICE\MSSQL$[SQLSERVERINSTANCE]` instead, (where [SQLSERVERINSTANCE] is replaced with your actual instance name).
4. Click OK. You will then see a list of the matching service accounts. Select MSSQLSERVER, and click OK to accept the selection.

[image]

[image]

You should see the service account listed in the security settings, and can adjust the permissions accordingly.

After adding permissions (I added Full Control, to match the default SQL Backup folder.) and restarting the SQL Server Management Console, I was able to select and restore my backup file.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/248315/list-of-hidden-virtual-windows-user-accounts tells us how to list user accounts on a computer. For any service named `s`, there is a virtual account named `NT Service\s`, even if the service does not run under that account.

Comment: The account I had to add was `NT Service\MSSQL$SQLSERVER2014`, perhaps because I named my instance `SQLSERVER2014`

Comment: I solved it by adding permissions for Computername\Users

Answer (score 17):

I got this today.

I turned off file sharing, indexing and cleared any open sessions (people logged in to copy backups), but problem did not go away.

Went to Windows Explorer, copied the backups to another folder and browsed to that one through Management Studio, and I could see it there.

Deleted the original folder and recreated it, copied contents back again and browsed to the `.bak` files and it was back to normal.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: it did help! :)

Comment: This is a typical answer in computing.  Lots of other complicated solutions which will swallow lots of your time, but this simple answer solved the problem for me too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I encountered this problem a couple of times. The issue is not with SQL Server but with Windows Permission of the folder. You have to add appropriate permission to the folder where you copied .bak file (I think `System Network` role).

The easier solution is, to move the file to the default back up folder in Program Files. It has all the necessary permission. For SQL Server 2012 it is

```
D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup
```

Comment: This is a great solution because one is not opening up potential security holes in their computer just to restore one file.

Comment: works great no need for policies and stuff

Comment: This is an appropriate answer. Worked excellent especially on Windows10

Answer (score 3):

I also came across the same issue today. I was given a backup file to restore but it was not visible to me while browsing. However I was able to acess the in file system but in in restore wizard using `SQL Server management Studio`.

After spending some I discovered that it is permissions issue. SQL Server Service is running using `Network Service` but `Network Service` account did not have permissions to access the folder. After granting the permissions to `Network Service`. Backup file was visible to restore.

For details please check by [Blog](http://ps-hayer.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/unable-to-locate-database-backup-bak.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you can find it in Windows Explorer, then you should write a `RESTORE DATABASE` command instead of relying on the clunky GUI to find it for you. Who knows what code is going on in there and why it might not be able to find the file - sorry I only have a workaround and not a solution.

Also ensure that the file is actually something.bak and not something.bak.txt (Windows may be "helpfully" hiding the extension from you. I hate that default behavior.)

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me today on my dev box. In my case, the service account had permissions to the folder, but my user account didn't. Once I granted my account permissions to the folder, I was able to see the .BAK files.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I accidentally connected to the WRONG server, obviously I couldn't find the backup file there....

The wrong server hostname differ only by a single letter, it's a mistake that was bound to happen. It's preferable to connect using "." or "localhost" instead of the full server hostname, if you're already logged in via RDP on the server.

[image]

In hindsight, try the command line instead of SSMS GUI. That will give you a clear error "file not found". This rules out a permissions issue.

```
USE [master];
GO
BACKUP DATABASE [AdventureWorks2019]
 TO DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQL2K17\MSSQL\Backup\AdventureWorks2019.bak'
    WITH COMPRESSION;
GO
```

Hope this helps!