# NT SERVICE\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS user cannot be found when added to network drive

Tags: sql-server, backup, permissions, windows

For SQL Server 2016 Express, I would like to backup/restore directly to/from network storage I have mapped to drive S:. SQL Server Express runs under the (virtual?) account `NT SERVICE\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS` as it should, which of course does not have the permissions to access S:.

As explained in 
[Broken NTFS Permissions for MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23864/broken-ntfs-permissions-for-mssqlsqlexpress)
I have tried to add `NT SERVICE\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS` to the users of S:. This fails with a "Name Not Found" message-box:

> An object named "NT SERVICE\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS" cannot be found.

My machine is not on a domain and has been restarted since S: and SQL Server Express were installed.

Why does it not find that user? Is there another way to make individual folders accessible to the default SQL Server user?

Comment: NT SERVICE\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS is a local account, it will exist on the server/computer where sql express is installed, but not on the network storage server. Did you actually map the S: drive locally, or are you just unc'ing (\\servername\share or \\servername\d$\) to it?

Comment: I have used "This PC" / "Map network drive..." to constantly map the network storage under S:. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

When you map that S: drive to a network share, you are using your local Windows account to do it (the user you're logged in as). However, SQL Server Express is running under a different account.

There are a few things you can try to work around this.

- Create a network share which has "Everyone" permission to write to, and then use the UNC path (`\\server\path`) as the target inside SQL Server for backups.
- Run the SQL Server service under a different account, which happens to coincide with an account using the same name and password on the network resource.
- Back up your databases to a local drive, and use some synchronization method (`ROBOCOPY`, `XCOPY`, etc.) to move those files to the network share, running under your normal Windows credentials. You can achieve this using the Windows Task Scheduler, running a PowerShell script or a Windows batch file.

Comment: Thanks Randolph, for the extensive workaround guide! So in seems with SQL-Server you need to go through lots of hoops to do a simple best-practice thing: Directly save a backup on a DIFFERENT media. :-(

Comment: Yeah, I always save locally first and then use a PowerShell or ROBOCOPY method to move or copy it off. More moving parts, but under better control. In a larger environment with domain access, I give the SQL account access to network shares and then it works as you expect.